# How a push notification behaves based on iOS application state

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I want to understand what will happen if a push notification arrives to device.

1. App Not running - what will happen if notification arrives - state change?
2. App is in foreground - ?
3. App is background - ?
4. App is inactive state ?

I am assuming if App is not running we can invoke by sending a silent push notification in some situations.

Can some one explain me how a push notification works based on app state.

Answer (score 0):

If the **application is not running** or in background state, if the user accepted to receive push notifications, the push notification will be sent to the device that will display it on screen.

From this displayed notification, you can launch or wake the target application.

The traditional launch callback:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

will be fired and you can access the received notification and its payload from its `launchOptions` dictionary, using `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` key.

If the **application is running** and in foreground, the AppDelegate method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

will be fired, `userInfo` containing the push notification payload.